# Javascript - Issue with caching and cookies

Tags: javascript, php, caching, cookies

I am getting quite a frustrating issue with JavaScript and Cookies on cached pages.

I got the following JS code:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
    if (!getCookie("lang") == "{{Lang}}"){
        document.reload();
    }
```

`{{Lang}}` is replaced with the very same cookie on the backend with PHP.

```
$template = str_replace("{{Lang}}", $lang, $template);
```

But that is not really relevant since that part works as intended.

The issue is that when the user visits a cached page.

The JS previously mentioned becomes

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
    if (!getCookie("lang") == "FR"){
        document.reload();
    }
```

The issue is that the page does not refresh even though the Chrome Dev tools quite clearly say that the cookie `lang` is set to "EN", not "FR".

Is there a method around this caching issue?

Comment: Why do you think the page is cached? Have you checked headers?

Comment: @zerkms Because it is not executing new PHP code which forced me to resort to this JS solution which doesn't seem to work either. But I want this solution to work because of interest for the issue and how to resolve it in the future.

Comment: "Because it is not executing new PHP code" --- how do you know it does not? Have you checked the server access log?

Comment: @zerkms I did a lot of troubleshooting on the issue. I know exactly what the problem is and I want to find how to resolve it. The problem is that getCookie() is not getting the latest cookie but one from a seemingly cached page.

Comment: "I know exactly what the problem is" --- so what is it? "the page is cached" does not sound like a technical enough explanation - provide some evidence it's really cached and it's not your wild guess. "from a seemingly cached page." --- good, and when I suggested you to explore it to know **for sure** you mentioned you already know it. That does not make much sense, sorry.

Comment: @zerkms Facts: Lang cookie is set to "EN" according to chrome dev tools. However even though "EN" obviously doesn't match "FR", it doesn't refresh.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74763/discussion-between-viruzx-and-zerkms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The not equal comparison in JS is `!=`, so

```
getCookie("lang") != "FR"
```

Answer (score 1):

The reload method accepts a Boolean flag indicating a force cache refresh.  So try:

```
document.reload(true);
```

Comment: Ha, that's useful to solve another issue I have but not the one at hand. The issue lies in the IF statement. It doesn't even get to that line.

Comment: "that's useful to solve another issue" --- it's not. You're not "solving" the issue, you're pretending there is no one. There is difference.